# Getting second row values from table is getting issue

Tags: php, mysql, moodle

I am trying to get the course attempt details where user attempted 2 times, so whenever I try to show 2 results its showing 2 results are same.

For example in first attempt if i failed and second attempt if i passed it showing  2 records data are passed only I don't know why it is happening like that.

Here is my code for that page:

```
<?php 
global $DB, $USER, $CFG; 
include("include/header.php"); 
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata'); 
?> 
<body> 
<div style=" 
margin: 50px 30px 5px 0px; 
float: right; 
"> 
<?php 
if ($_SESSION['idnumber'] == 3) { 
?> 
<a href="link_courses.php"><button type="submit" name="linkcourses" value="linkcourses" class="btn btn-primary">Link Exam</button></a> 
<a href="createaccesscode.php"><button type="submit" name="accesscode" value="accesscode" class="btn btn-primary">Access Code</button></a> 
<a href="createsingleuser.php"><button type="submit" name="accesscode" value="accesscode" class="btn btn-primary">Create Single User</button></a> 
<button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#contact_dialog" type="submit" name="accesscode" value="accesscode" class="btn btn-primary" style="cursor: pointer;">Max No. of Users</button> 
<button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#bulk_upload" type="submit" name="accesscode" value="accesscode" class="btn btn-primary" style="cursor: pointer;">Bulk User Upload</button> 
<a href="report.php"><button type="submit" name="accesscode" value="accesscode" class="btn btn-primary">Report</button></a> 
<a href="creategroup.php"><button type="submit" name="accesscode" value="accesscode" class="btn btn-primary">Groups</button></a> 
<?php 
} 
if ($_SESSION['idnumber'] == 2) { 
?> 
<a href="report.php"><button type="submit" name="accesscode" value="accesscode" class="btn btn-primary">Report</button></a> 
<?php 
} 
?> 
</div> 
<div class="container-fluid"style="background: #dddadd"> 
<div style=" 
margin: 50px 15px 5px 0px; 
float: right; 
"> 
<?php 
if ($_SESSION['idnumber'] == 3) { 
?> 
<?php 
} 
?> 
</div> 

<div class="row" style=" margin-top: 20px;"> 

<div class="col-lg-12"> 
<div class="panel panel-default"> 

<div class="panel-body" id="report_grid"> 
<div class="table-responsive" style="font-family: myFirstFont;"> 
<table id="datatable2" class="table"> 
<thead> 
<tr> 

<th style="color: #005EB8">Course</th> 
<th style="color: #005EB8">Username</th> 
<th style="color: #005EB8">First Name</th> 
<th style="color: #005EB8">Last Name</th> 
<th style="color: #005EB8">Total Time</th> 
<th style="color: #005EB8">Start Date</th> 
<th style="color: #005EB8">Completion Date</th> 
<th style="color: #005EB8">Attempt</th> 
<th style="color: #005EB8">Status</th> 
<th style="color: #005EB8">Exam score</th> 

</tr> 
</thead> 
<tbody> 
<?php 
require_once($CFG->dirroot . '/mod/scorm/lib.php'); 
require_once($CFG->dirroot . '/mod/scorm/locallib.php'); 
require_once($CFG->dirroot . '/course/lib.php'); 

global $DB; 
//course table fetch 
$sql1 = "SELECT cm.id as cmid,c.id,c.fullname,c.startdate,c.startdate,instance FROM {course} c LEFT JOIN {course_modules} cm ON c.id=cm.course where c.category != 0 and requested='0' AND cm.id!=''"; 
$courses = $DB->get_records_sql($sql1); 

if (sizeof($courses)) { 
foreach ($courses as $row) { 

$scorm = $DB->get_record("scorm", array("id" => $row->instance)); 
$scoid = 0; 
$orgidentifier = ''; 
if ($sco = scorm_get_sco($scorm->launch, SCO_ONLY)) { 
if (($sco->organization == '') && ($sco->launch == '')) { 
$orgidentifier = $sco->identifier; 
} else { 
$orgidentifier = $sco->organization; 
} 
$scoid = $sco->id; 
} 
$cmid = $row->cmid; 
$coursename = $row->fullname; 






$useridQry = ''; 
$userIds = ''; 
$login_id = $_SESSION['USER']->id; 

if ($_SESSION['idnumber'] == 3) { 

} elseif ($_SESSION['idnumber'] == 2) { 
$records = $DB->get_records_sql("select * from {user} where maildigest=$login_id"); 
if (count($records)) { 
foreach ($records as $row) { 
$userIds[] = "'" . $row->id . "'"; 
} 
if ($userIds != '') { 
$userIds = implode(',', $userIds); 
$useridQry = " and st.userid IN ($userIds)"; 
} 
} 
} else { 
$useridQry = "and st.userid = $login_id"; 
} 


$scom_id = $row->cmid; 
$cm = get_coursemodule_from_id('scorm', $scom_id, 0, false, MUST_EXIST); 
$course = $DB->get_record('course', array('id' => $cm->course), '*', MUST_EXIST); 
$scorm = $DB->get_record('scorm', array('id' => $cm->instance), '*', MUST_EXIST); 


$query = "SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT(u.id, '#', COALESCE(st.attempt,0)) AS uniqueid, st.scormid AS scormid,st.value, st.attempt AS attempt, u.id AS userid,u.picture,u.firstname,u.lastname,u.username,u.firstnamephonetic,u.lastnamephonetic,u.middlename,u.alternatename,u.imagealt,u.email,u.idnumber FROM mdl_user u LEFT JOIN mdl_scorm_scoes_track st ON st.userid = u.id AND st.scormid = $scorm->id WHERE (st.userid IS NOT NULL) and idnumber != 0 $useridQry"; 
$attempts = 0; 
$attempts = $DB->get_records_sql($query); 
//print_r($attempts); 
$row = array(); 

if (isset($attempts)) { 
foreach ($attempts as $scouser) { 
//print_r($scouser); 
$type = ''; 
$status = ''; 
$totaltime = ''; 
$score = ''; 

if (!empty($scouser->attempt)) { 
$timetracks = scorm_get_sco_runtime($scorm->id, false, $scouser->userid, $scouser->attempt); 
} else { 
$timetracks = ''; 
} 
//echo $timetracks; 

global $DB; 
$tracks = $DB->get_records_sql("SELECT id, element, value FROM {scorm_scoes_track} WHERE scormid = ? AND userid = ? AND element IN('cmi.core.lesson_status','cmi.core.total_time','cmi.core.score.raw')", array($scorm->id, $scouser->userid)); 

foreach ($tracks as $trac) { 
if ($trac->element == 'cmi.core.lesson_status') { 
$status = $trac->value; 
} 
if ($trac->element == 'cmi.core.total_time') { 
$totaltime = $trac->value; 
} 
if ($trac->element == 'cmi.core.score.raw') { 
$score = $trac->value; 
} 


$scouser->times = $timetracks; 
$scouser->status = $status; 
$scouser->totaltime = $totaltime; 
$scouser->score = $score; 
$row[] = $scouser; 

$start_date = $finish_date = ''; 
if (isset($scouser->times)) { 
if (isset($scouser->times->start)) 
$start_date = date('Y-M-d H-i-s', $scouser->times->start); 
if (isset($scouser->times->finish)) 
$finish_date = date('Y-M-d H-i-s', $scouser->times->finish); 
} 
} //foreach score track ends 


?> 
<tr class="gradeX"> 

<td ><?php echo $coursename; ?></td> 
<td ><?php echo $scouser->username; ?></td> 
<td ><?php echo $scouser->firstname; ?></td> 
<td ><?php echo $scouser->lastname; ?></td> 
<td ><?php echo $totaltime; ?></td> 
<td ><?php echo $start_date; ?></td> 
<td ><?php echo $finish_date; ?></td> 
<td ><?php echo $scouser->attempt; ?></td> 

<td> 

<?php 
//print_r($tracks); 
//echo $status; 
if (trim($status) == "completed") { 

echo " Completed"; 
} elseif (trim($status) == "incomplete") { 

echo "Incomplete"; 
} elseif (trim($status) == "failed") { 

echo "Failed"; 
} elseif (trim($status) == "passed") { 

echo "Passed"; 
} else { 

echo "Not Started"; 
} 
?> 
</td> 
<td> 
<?php 
if ($score == "") { 

} else { 
echo $score; 
echo '%'; 
} 
//echo $score; 
?> 
</td> 
</tr> 
<?php 


} //foreach 104 ends 
}//attempts if ends 

} //course foreach ends 

}//course if ends 

?> 



</tbody> 
</table> 
</div> 
</div> 
</div> 
</div> 
</div> 

</body> 
<?php 
include("include/footer.php"); 
?> 
</html>
```

Comment: In Moodle, records retrieved by get_records are indexed by the first field retrieved, as stated in the docs https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Data_manipulation_API . If the first item contains any repeats, then records will be overwritten in the result. If this is a problem, use something else as the first field, or use get_recordset instead.

Comment: so if i use get_record set instead will it solve my problem or what is the another way can you please expalin me

Comment: Anywhere you can't find a unique field to put first in the list of fields, get_recordset_sql will fix it. You will then be able to loop through the result, but you won't get an array of results. Note, much of the rest of the code is not written that well and could do with a rewrite, but this should fix the immediate problem.

Comment: yes exactly the first item contains repeats only means one course is attempted by one user with 2 attempts..

Comment: I can't really make it any clearer, if the first field retrieved by the query, I.e. the first field after the word SELECT can contain repeats, then get_records_sql will not include those repeats. If you're really not sure, then stick the queries into Phpmyadmin and looks through the results.

Comment: i tried with get_recordset its not solved my problem

Comment: can you please help me to solve that one